# Find duplicate rows conditionally in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Problem**
I need to filter a set of records conditionally. The rules for filter the data are: find duplicate values by **ProductNumber** and also they need to have a least two **ProductType** (1 and 5)

**Example**
Product

| ProductNumber | ProductType | ProductName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A-000217 | 1 | stuff 13 |
| A-000217 | 5 | stuff 13 |
| A-000086 | 5 | stuff 2 |
| A-000086 | 5 | stuff 2 |
| A-001229 | 1 | stuff 20 |
| A-001146 | 5 | stuff 21 |
| A-001146 | 1 | stuff 21 |

This should be the output

Product (Filtered)

| ProductNumber | ProductType | ProductName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A-000217 | 1 | stuff 13 |
| A-000217 | 5 | stuff 13 |
| A-001146 | 5 | stuff 21 |
| A-001146 | 1 | stuff 21 |

- Product A-000086 has been excluded because both records are type 5.
- Product A-001229 only has 1 record so it must be excluded.

I tried this code, but it didn't work as expected.

```
CREATE TABLE #Product(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1)  NOT NULL,
    [ProductNumber] [varchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [ProductType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductName] [varchar](60) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);

INSERT INTO [#Product]([ProductNumber], [ProductType], [ProductName])
 VALUES('A-000217', 1, 'stuff 13')
,('A-000217', 5, 'stuff 13')
,('A-000086', 5, 'stuff 2')
,('A-000086', 5, 'stuff 2')
,('A-001229', 1, 'stuff 20')
,('A-001146', 5, 'stuff 21')
,('A-001146', 1, 'stuff 21')

--Filter data
; WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 
      ProductNumber 
    , ProductType 
    , ProductName
    , COUNT(ProductType) OVER(PARTITION BY ProductNumber) AS [RowNumber]
 FROM #Product
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RowNumber > 1
```

Result:

[image: output]

What's wrong with my code? Or how can I achieve this approach?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY`in the `CTE` with `HAVING` for total for every product number and also for `DISTINCT` type yields the result you are searching for

> ```
> WITH CTE AS
> (SELECT
> [ProductNumber], [ProductName]
> FROM 
> [#Product]
> GROUP BY [ProductNumber], [ProductName] 
> HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND COUNT(DISTINCT [ProductType]) > 1)
> SELECT p1.[ProductNumber], p1.[ProductType], p1.[ProductName] 
> FROM [#Product] p1 JOIN CTE p2 ON p1.[ProductNumber] = p2.[ProductNumber]
> ```
>
> ```
> ProductNumber | ProductType | ProductName
> :------------ | ----------: | :----------
> A-000217      |           1 | stuff 13   
> A-000217      |           5 | stuff 13   
> A-001146      |           5 | stuff 21   
> A-001146      |           1 | stuff 21
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=28306158b05e1c6102d34043b18e2c77)*

Answer (score 0):

This is not very intuitive, but it works. You want `ProductNumberCount` to be 2 or more (both 1 and 5), but `ProductTypeCount` to be 1 (only one item of each `1` and `5`, per `ProductNumber`). And perhaps not bad idea to filter only for `1` and `5` in `CTE` itself.

```sql
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
          ProductNumber 
        , ProductType 
        , ProductName
        , COUNT(ProductNumber) OVER(PARTITION BY ProductNumber) AS [ProductNumberCount]
        , COUNT(ProductType) OVER(PARTITION BY ProductNumber, ProductType) AS [ProductTypeCount]
     FROM #Product
     WHERE ProductType IN (1, 5)
)
SELECT ProductNumber
    ,ProductType
    ,ProductName
FROM CTE WHERE CTE.ProductNumberCount >= 2 AND CTE.ProductTypeCount = 1
```

Example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b9211cfd7975b3ba63c83f15baa33d3e)

Answer (score 0):

One other way is a correlated query using *exists* which should be performant:

```
select * 
from #Product p
where exists (
    select * from #Product p2
    where p2.ProductNumber = p.ProductNumber
    group by p2.productNumber
    having Min(p2.productType) = 1 and Max(p2.productType) = 5
);
```

Demo [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a605ce411f430cb592e91c3a8707b15c)